# Steema Charts performance within ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, teechart

Does anyone have any experience using Steema Teecharts within a viewpager on Android?

I have 5 charts within a viewpager - they get created once and cached.  Swiping between the pages is really choppy.  I am testing out the evaluation version, which is adding a watermark to the charts and I am wondering if the choppiness is because of the watermark?  Profiling indicates the lag is in the onDraw code of the charts.

Can anyone who has used Teecharts tell me if this problem exists in the non-eval version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to call "setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)" on the chart object. It made a significant difference. Not sure why that is, as the Android docs make it sound like it would not help as I have hardware acceleration enabled, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the watermark affects the performance a lot.

Do your charts have many points? Note the number of points being drawn is one of the aspects that affects the performance. Try if playing with the number of points changes your app response.

Does the demo in the market reproduce the problem in your device? If so, what device are you using?

--

Best Regards,

Yeray Alonso

Steema Support Central

Comment: Hi Yeray, thanks for the comment.   My solution was to call "setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)" on the chart object.   It made a significant difference.   Not sure why that is, as the Android docs make it sound like it would not help as I have hardware acceleration enabled, but it did.

Comment: Hi! Good to see you found how to make it work. And thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this same problem enabling the drawing cache helped a little bit, but the real problem for me was the autoredraw.  This was causing the OnPaintListener to be called almost constantly.  I was able to disable this by setting the setAutoRepaint to false.  This dropped CPU usage to a for more normal level.